# Does $P(R\vert Q,P) = P(R\vert Q)$ implies that $R$ is independent of $P$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

I would like to know -- given $P,Q,R$ are three distinct events --
if from  $P(R\vert Q,P)= P(R\vert Q)$ follows that $R$ is independent of $P$.

I can see that in order for this to be true it must be that
$$P(R\vert Q,P)= \frac{P(R\cap Q\cap P)}{P(Q\cap P)} = \frac{P(R\cap Q) P(P)}{P(Q)P(P)} =  P(R\vert Q)$$.

So we must have that $(R\cap Q)\perp P$ and $Q\perp P$ (provided, for this latter conclusion that P is not a subset of Q). But it looks to me like this does not implies that $R\perp P$ in general, is that correct?

Comment: I don't agree with your penultimate sentence - consider the case where $P$, $Q$, and $R$ are all the same event.

Comment: Ok, got rid of this edge case.

Comment: I still don't believe the conclusion $P \perp Q$. For example, suppose we are rolling a die and $P$ is "we roll a 3 or lower", $Q$ is "we roll a 2 or lower", and $R$ is "we roll a 1". Or in general any case where $P$ is always true when $Q$ is true.

Comment: I see what you mean, I will edit accordingly to rule this case out. Thanks!

Comment: That isn't the only problematic case though - for example, suppose $P$ is "we roll a 1", $Q$ is "we roll a 2", and $R$ is "we roll a 1 or a 2". Then $P$ and $Q$ are independent and disjoint. The flaw in your derivation is that if two fractions are equal, it need not follow that their numerators are equal and their denominators are equal.

Comment: Oops, that should have read "$P$ and $Q$ are *not* independent and are disjoint".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means $R$ is independent of $P$ given $Q$. So, it is [conditional independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20two%20random,their%20conditional%20probability%20distribution%20given%20.). Conditional independence doesn't mean that the two events/random variables are independent. Also, if the two events/random variables are independent, it also doesn't mean that they're conditionally independent given some other event/random variable.

Comment: I get what you mean, but you may want to clarify your wording to make it clear that $R\perp P$ does not hold in general, but there is a specific conditional sense in which it is independent of P (thanks for the name which I had never heard)

Comment: @ThreeDiag I've added some more explanation, indicating that neither result can imply the other.